# Python. ¿como hacer que se guarden en variables diferentes los resultados de un ciclo while o for los elementos de un array?

Tags: python, variables, guardar

llevo horas tratando de guardar en variables diferentes los elementos de una lista
intente esto sin exito:

```
listaNumeros = ['12 + 3', '345 + 99', '34 - 45']

v1 = listaNumeros[0]
v2 = listaNumeros[1]
v2 = listaNumeros[3]


print(v1, v2, v3)
```

la salida de eso es:
v1

v2

v3

y no es eso lo que buscaba, quiero imprimir uno debajo del otro los elementos de la lista.

trate de hacerlo con un ciclo while y un ciclo for.
pero claro, se me guarda cada vuelta en una variable sola, almacenandose solo el ultimo resultado de la iteracion.
¿habra alguna manera de que luego de recorrer cada vuelta me guarde cada elemento de la lista de manera separada ?
lo que tenia hecho hasta el momento con ciclos es esto, pero no supe como continuar.

```
listaNumeros = ['12 + 3', '345 + 99', '34 - 45']

for i in (listaNumeros)  :
     while i < 4 :
        if len(listaNumeros) <4 :
       op =listanumeros[i]`
```

la idea es generar un op1, op2, op3 que guarde respectivamente cada elemento de la lista

probe anteriormente con `enumerate()` pero no, con `len(enumerate())`.. no se que hacer ya
gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Y para que quieres eso? Con que fin?

Comment: estoy haciendo un challenge en freecode camp, y una de las cosas que se requieren es imrimir una suma en forma vertical con cierta estructura. para ello necesito poder acceder a cada elemento de la lista de manera individual, para luego hacer otras cosas.  . la idea es acceder a, por ejemplo (13 + 15), y que se imprima en forma vertical, con ciertos espacios.  como las sumas que se hacen en papel. uno debajo del otro...gracias por tu interes :)

Comment: Si revisas la documentación de `print` vas a ver que tiene un argumento `sep` que puedes configurar con `\n` para que cada elemento se imprima en una nueva línea. Aunque según recuerdo ese reto pide imprimir varias sumas en paralelo por lo que debes crear la línea con los datos de todas las sumas por fila.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo estoy revisando ! :=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque la respuesta ha sido contestada, como no tiene código propongo uno:

```
lista_operaciones = ['12 + 3', '345 + 99', '34 - 45']

for operacion in lista_operaciones:
    n1, signo, n2 = operacion.split()
    largo = len(max(operacion.split(), key=len)) + 6
    print(f'{n1:>{largo}}  '
          f'\n{signo}{n2:>{largo-1}}  '
          f'\n{"-"*largo}  '
          f'\n{eval(operacion):>{largo}}\n')
```

Con la expresión `largo = len(max(operacion.split(), key=len)) + 6` se calcula el maximo de longitud de los números para poder imprimirlos uno debajo de otro.

En la expresión `print(f'{n1:>{largo}}  '` hay llaves anidadas para que `largo` lo entienda como una variable y no un literal.

La salida por pantalla sería:

```
      12  
+      3  
--------  
      15

      345  
+      99  
---------  
      444

      34  
-     45  
--------  
     -11
```

Como `eval()` puede generar problemas de seguridad, mejor crear una función que realice las operaciones, con lo que quedaría así:

```
def operar(operador, a, b):
    a, b = int(a), int(b)
    if operador == '+': return a+b
    if operador == '-': return a-b
    if operador == '*': return a*b
    try:
        return a//b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return '----'
    

lista_operaciones = ['12 + 3', '345 + 99', '34 - 45']

for operacion in lista_operaciones:
    n1, signo, n2 = operacion.split()
    largo = len(max(operacion.split(), key=len)) + 6
    print(f'{n1:>{largo}}  '
          f'\n{signo}{n2:>{largo-1}}  '
          f'\n{"-"*largo}  '
          f'\n{operar(signo, n1, n2):>{largo}}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a almacenar cada uno de los datos en una posición de un array utilizando los bucles como estas haciendo. Y a la hora de printear, mediante otro bucle, ir printeando individualmente cada posición y tras cada impresión poner un `\n` para insertar un intro y saltar de línea.

Comment: Explica tu respuesta: 1) `i` es un string; no puedes hacer `while i < 4`. 2) La lista no cambia; preguntar repetidamente su largo no tiene sentido. 3) El `print` siempre pone un`\n` al final.